# Given a dataframe containing time delays: how to tell by what point 90% of delays have occurred

Tags: r, percentage

I have a set of observations that measure time delay from an initial event, such as the elapsed time from when an email is sent to when it is opened.

Given a set of 100 observations, how can I tell at what point in time 90 percent of the opens took place. I want to be able to say "90 % of the opens took place within 4 hours of send time."

I can generate a histogram of delays, which shows that most opens happen early, but I do not know how to get a cumulative measure for all counts in the bins.  (I'm not explaining myself very well, not a stats wonk)

So with this sample data I have 10 observations with a delay of 1 hour, 5 with a delay of 2 hours, 3 with a delay of 3 hours and 2 with a delay of 4 hours. This means that 90% of the opens came within less than 4 hours.  How do I determine that 90% limit for a real set of observations?

**Edited with more compact sample data creation and added first cut at plot of cumulative percentage.  Would welcome better solutions.**

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
all_delays <- tibble(delay = rep(1:4, c(10, 5, 3, 2)))
all_delays
#> # A tibble: 20 x 1
#>    delay
#>    <int>
#>  1     1
#>  2     1
#>  3     1
#>  4     1
#>  5     1
#>  6     1
#>  7     1
#>  8     1
#>  9     1
#> 10     1
#> 11     2
#> 12     2
#> 13     2
#> 14     2
#> 15     2
#> 16     3
#> 17     3
#> 18     3
#> 19     4
#> 20     4

# histogram of data
ggplot(all_delays) + aes(delay) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,1))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
# newbie incorrect way to get plot of cumulative percentage.
# would welcome better way to do this.
all_delays <- all_delays %>% mutate(cnt = 1) %>% 
  arrange(delay) %>%
  mutate(cs = cumsum(cnt))
ggplot(all_delays) + aes(cs/nrow(all_delays),delay) + 
  geom_line()  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,.25,.50,.75,.90,1), 
                     labels=c("0","25%","50%","75%","90%","100%")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept =.9) +
  xlab("Cumulative Percentage of opens") +
  ylab("hours since open")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I guess my expected results are something that would say "90% limit = 3", or some kind of cumulative curve that would start at the shortest open delay and then increase in value until 100 % was reached with a tick at 90 %.

**Thanks for the `quantile()` answer!**

Email open rates typically have a long tail where mot activity happens within a day or two of the email send, and then a very long tail as people browse their email inboxes weeks or even months after the email was sent.

Comment: off-topic: `rep` accepts a vector as `times` argument so you could create that `delay` column using `delay = rep(1:4, c(10, 5, 3, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is called a *quantile*.  The code below removes all delays above the 90th percentile; i.e., the remaining delays give you the points by which 90% of the events have occurred.

```
> all_delays %>% filter(delay <= quantile(delay, 0.9))
# A tibble: 18 x 1
   delay
   <dbl>
 1     1
 2     1
 3     1
 4     1
 5     1
 6     1
 7     1
 8     1
 9     1
10     1
11     2
12     2
13     2
14     2
15     2
16     3
17     3
18     3
```

Comment: Awesome!  So if I took the max delay value of that subset data frame, there is my answer.

Comment: You can also compute the 90th percentile directly: `quantile(all_delays$delay, 0.9)`.